# Deploy django as war - Jython

Tags: django, jython

I'm trying to deploy a django app as war (to use with JBOSS server). I have seen the documentation and I made this:

```
jython manage.py builder --include-java-libs=/usr/share/java/jython/jython.jar
```

And I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not activated that environment where you installed Python and other dependent packages for application.

Activate the environment and then run:

```
jython manage.py builder --include-java-libs=/usr/share/java/jython/jython.jar
```

Then it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jython -m pip list
```

In the list check the package name **django** is there or not. Also, check for package **django-jython**.

To install this package to jython installation directory, run this command:

```
jython -m pip install django
jython -m pip install django-jython
```

To build war file, use this command:

```
jython manage.py buildwar --include-java-libs=/path/to/jython-standalone.jar
```